# Unveiling the Secrets of Lock Portrait: How to Programmatically Determine Portrait Mode Lock Status in iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, flutter, user-interface

I am currently facing a challenge in my iOS app development. I need to programmatically retrieve the status of the Auto Rotate setting in iOS, specifically the lock status of the Portrait Mode.

Could you please provide guidance on how to obtain the lock status of the Portrait Mode programmatically in iOS? I want to adapt my app's behavior based on this information to ensure a seamless user experience.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance, insights, or code snippets that can help me address this problem effectively.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/D9AWh.jpg

I expect to obtain the lock status of the Portrait Mode programmatically in iOS. The desired result would provide me with information on whether the Portrait Mode is currently locked or unlocked on the device.

I am seeking guidance, suggestions, or sample code snippets that can help me retrieve this lock status effectively using Swift in my iOS app development.